# Batch to iterate through an array with elements that contain spaces?

Tags: batch-file

I need to iterate through an array to append to .txt files, but I have spaces inside each element. I havent found how to enclose an array element so the spaces within each are ignored.

I used quotes but they show up in the file.

```
 Set array= "a b" "a c" "a d"

 Set x=1
 For %%a in (%names%) do (
  >file!x!.txt (
   Echo %%a
  )
  Set /a x+=1
 )
```

This shows "a b" in the first file.
How do think I can get rid of the quotations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Echo %%~a
```

(I thought that one was coming...)

Comment: Haha. Thanks magoo!

Comment: @RichM Remember to check this as your answer by clicking on the gray checkmark to turn it green :) This will also reward you!

Answer (score -1):

**Its simple, try concat a varible = %%20 to your urls**

For example, for this url array:

```
SET URLs = url/path1 with emptys, path2.com
```

do:

```
SET "emptyVal = %%20"
SET URLs= url/path1%emptyVal%with%emptyVal%emptys, path2.com
SET NewTab=-new-tab
FOR %%a in ("%URLs%") DO (Start /d "%programfiles(x86)%\Mozilla Firefox" Firefox.exe %NewTab% "%%a")
```

This code also open the urls in Firefox tabs.